# How Pandas is doing groupby for below scenario

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am facing problem while trying to understand the below code snippet of group by.I am trying to understand how is calculation is happening for df.groupby(L).sum().

This is a code snippet that i got from the url[enter link description here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.08-aggregation-and-grouping.html).
Thanks for any help.

[image: Initialising value to data frame]

[image: Pandas group by result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rows are grouping by values of list, because length of list is same like number of rows in `DataFrame`, it means:

```
rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'data1': range(6),
                   'data2': rng.randint(0, 10, 6)},
                   columns = ['key', 'data1', 'data2'])
L = [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0]
print (df)
  key  data1  data2
0   A      0      5 <-0
1   B      1      0 <-1
2   C      2      3 <-0
3   A      3      3 <-1
4   B      4      7 <-2
5   C      5      9 <-0
```

So:

```
data1 for 0 is 0 + 2 + 5 = 7
data2 for 0 is 5 + 3 + 9 = 17

data1 for 1 is 1 + 3 = 4
data2 for 1 is 0 + 3 = 3

data1 for 2 is 4
data2 for 2 is 7
```

Output:

```
print(df.groupby(L).sum())
   data1  data2
0      7     17
1      4      3
2      4      7
```

Key column is omitted, because [Automatic exclusion of 'nuisance' columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns).